# How to customize the right-pane of windows explorer using Shell extensions?

Tags: shell, winapi, explorer

Is there a way to create a custom right (or bottom) pane attached to a window in explorer as in the image below?
I was already able to add a button as you can check in the picture.

I already searched but didn't find any example for panels.
Can anyone give me some hints?

thanks

[image]

Comment: The question was re-posted as the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Is possible using Explorer Bar.
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: These are deprecated.  Also, these bars show up on the left, not the right...

Comment: Also these bars may be on the left, not only right.