# How to extend Windows Explorer with a custom panel

Tags: c#, windows, shell, windows-explorer

I would like to extend Windows Explorer with a custom bottom or right panel (like the image below).

From what I have been reading, I think I should start by implementing IShellView. Is this correct? Can anyone give me a few pointers how to do this in .net?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: [Shell extensions written in C# are not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen. And in C++? Any hints how to do it?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is an Explorer Bar, [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: As pointed by Raymond Chen or Xearinox in your previous question - CREATE EXPLORER BAR AND DONT ASK DUPLICATE QUESTION!

Comment: @RaymondChen: thanks but it seems that Explorar Bar are no longer supported in Win7 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_features_removed_in_Windows_7). Any other hints?

Comment: Then that area is no longer externsible.

Comment: DON'T RE-POST the [same question again](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22082067/1523648). Instead, edit the question to add details when needed.

Comment: though quite error prone, I figured this out, I can send u a copy of my code if u still need this. PS. i do this in C++. @pinker

Comment: @Sean, I would really appreciate if you send me your solution.

Comment: @pinker what's your mailbox addr? cannot find one in your profile.

Comment: @Sean: is danieladacruz @ gmail.com

Comment: @Sean I also want to know how to implement it in C++. Could you send me a copy of your code if possible?

Answer (score 3):

You must implement IDockingWindow. Result will be look like this:

[image]

One of the scenario:

1) Create BHO with IObjectWithSite support.

2) Inside IObjectWithSite.SetSite call Site.QueryInterface(IServiceProvider, ServiceProvider)

3)Then call ServiceProvider.QueryService(SID_SShellBrowser, IDockingWindowFrame, DockingWindowFrame).

4) Then call DockingWindowFrame.AddToolbar with your object that implements IDockingWindow and IObjectWithSite.

5) Inside IObjectWithSite of your object call QueryInterface(IDockingWindowSite, DockingWindowSite)

Other detail you can find in the MSDN.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @Denis. I have the following code: 
`object webBrowser; 
provider.QueryService(ref guid, ref riid, out webBrowser);                     
this.explorer = webBrowser as InternetExplorer;`

How do I change it to get the Explorer windows instead of InternetExplorer?

Comment: Which interface you want to receive?

Comment: I want to get a pointer to the Windows Explorer and not the InternetExplorer. Should I use `ShellBrowserWindow`? Thanks a lot. I am new in writing these kind of things.

Comment: What you mean when you write "get a pointer to the Windows Explorer"? What do you want to do? If you want to add new panel to Explorer just use the code I wrote in the answer.

Comment: Ok. I suppose I am doing it wrong. Can you give me some pointers of some code doing something similar?

Comment: Hey guys, I am now trying to do the exact same thing here, but in C++ instead. I find Denis' instructions are not easy for me to follow. I tried the methods, but I'm sutck at how to properly call AddToolBar cuz I don't know when and how to create my window cuz I don't know how to get a parent window(the explorer)'s hanlde, I mean I can't just create a window and show it , right? Could u kindly please elaborate this in more details ? Thanks a lot guys!! @pinker

Comment: Hi @Sean. Unfortunately I was unable to go further with this. I didn't find the help I needed.